# unary increment operator within a string doesn't work

Tags: powershell

suppose we set a variable, $i = 0, then

```
"-$i-" => "-0-"
"-$($i)-" => "-0-"
```

the above is as I would expect, but this fails:

```
"-$(++$i)-" => "--"  # I expected "-1-"
```

however, expressions do work.  for example:

```
"-$(pwd)-" => "-C:\temp-"
```

so what's going on here?

Comment: I always found inline string expressions to be unreliable, and preferred string formatters: `'-{0}-' -f ++$i`. Also, in the second example, `$i` did get incremented, just not displayed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh847875.aspx), this is expected behavior

> The increment operator (++) increases the value of a variable by 1.
>   When
>       you use the increment operator in a simple statement, no value is returned.
>       To view the result, display the value of the variable, as follows:
>
> ```
>     C:\PS> $a = 7
>     C:\PS> ++$a
>     C:\PS> $a
>     8
> ```
>
> To force a value to be returned, enclose the variable and the operator
>   in parentheses, as follows:
>
> ```
>     C:\PS> $a = 7
>     C:\PS> (++$a)
>     8
> ```

The shortest way around this is the following statement:

```
"-$((++$i))-" #=> -4-
```

Since the extra set of Parentheses tell it to return the value, as opposed to just execute the statement.

Comment: incidentally, I found that `"-$([string] ++$i)-"` will also work